# Calculating Date ranges in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a date field that I would like to results returned where the date is minus a given amount of days.  For example, WHERE @today - 30 would give me the last 30 days of data.  How can I do this?

Comment: SQL Server or Sybase? In SQL Server at least, if `@today` is a `datetime` variable then `SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE DateColumn >= @today-30` might actually do what you want. But it isn't obvious what you're trying to do anyway, so please give some more details of what your query and what your goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculating date ranges you can use:-

```
WHERE date_column BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Now for subtracting you can use:-

```
 DATEADD(DAY, -30, '9/1/2011')
```

something like:=

```
 WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN dateAdd(day,-30,date1) AND date2
```

Comment: What I am looking for more specifically is today minus multiple sets of days.  30days = today - 30, 60days = today - 60, 120days = today -120 so on and so forth...

Comment: So if you are creating a stored procedure then you can create an input parameter say @days where you are passing the days(30,60,120) and you can use it like:- WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN dateAdd(day,-@days,date1) AND date2 hope that resolves your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dateAdd. The syntax of `day` may vary based on your DBMS

```
WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN dateAdd(day,-30,getDate()) AND getDate()
```

or

```
WHERE datecolumn > dateAdd(day,-30,getDate())
```